# Give different variable value to last enum value

Tags: java, enums

I want the last enum to have a different value in one of the variables:

```
private enum thing {
    thing0(0),
    thing1(1),
    thing2(2);

    int index;
    String s;

    private thing(int index) {
        this.index = index;
        s = index == values().length - 1 ? "b" : "a";
    }
}
```

This doesn't work; you can't call `values()` in the constructor. Is there another way?

Comment: Do the check in the getter for `s`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, don't rely on the declaration order of the enum values. Item 35 in *Effective Java* 3rd Ed, "Use instance fields instead of ordinals", explains why. (Note that whilst you are using an instance field for `s`, its value depends on the ordinal.)

If you want a particular value to have a particular property, pass it in as a constructor parameter.

```
private enum thing {
    thing0(0),
    thing1(1),
    thing2(2, "b");

    int index;
    String s;

    private thing(int index) {
        this(index, "a");
    }

    private thing(int index, String s) {
        this.index = index;
        this.s = s;
    }
}
```

---

If you really do want it to be checking for the last value in the enum, an alternative way to do this is with a getter. Initialize a static final field in the enum to be the last value:

```
// Invokes `values()` twice, but meh, it's only executed once.
private static final thing LAST = values()[values().length-1];
```

Then check in a getter:

```
String s() {
  return this == LAST ? "b" : "a";
}
```

Comment: The declaration order of the enum values is used whenever the order of `values()` is used. I want the last value, not a particular value, to have the different string, even if more values are added.

Comment: @H.v.M. sure. But don't rely on the order never being changed in the source code. The example given in EJ is of an enum where a "helpful" colleague sorts the names, which will have an unintended semantic change on the value of `s`.

Comment: @H.v.M. "I want the last value, not a particular value, to have the different string, even if more values are added." sounds like a rather brittle requirement. Can you explain why you want this?

Comment: The enum in my actual case is `COLUMN` and the last column should have a different layout data that makes it take up the remaining column space.

Comment: @H.v.M. that sounds like something that is a property of the layout, rather than of the column itself, and as such shouldn't be part of the column.

Comment: Well it doesn't contain the actual data, just index, header, layout data and label provider.

Comment: @Holger there's no circular dependency in what I have suggested. `LAST` isn't accessed in the constructor, it's accessed in a getter.

Comment: Yes, it does work in a getter. It wouldn’t work in a constructor, as the OP attempted. I removed my misleading comment.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to maintain an index that always matches the [ordinal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal()) of the `enum` constant. Further, you can’t rely on the `values()` array in the constructor as it is supposed to contain the already constructed instances. But to determine, how many constants exist, it is enough to count the associated fields.

```java
public enum Thing {
    thing0,
    thing1,
    thing2;
  
    final String s;
  
    Thing() {
        this.s = ordinal() == numConstants() - 1? "b": "a";
    }
  
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name() + "(index = " + ordinal() + ", s = " + s + ")";
    }
  
    private static int NUM_CONSTANTS;
  
    private static int numConstants() {
        int i = NUM_CONSTANTS;
        if(i != 0) return i;
        for(Field f: Thing.class.getDeclaredFields()) if(f.isEnumConstant()) i++;
        NUM_CONSTANTS = i;
        return i;
    }
}
```

So `System.out.println(EnumSet.allOf(Thing.class));` prints

```
[thing0(index = 0, s = a), thing1(index = 1, s = a), thing2(index = 2, s = b)]
```

Note that `numConstants()` caches the value in `NUM_CONSTANTS` which is safe as the `private` method is only invoked within the class initializer. We can’t use a `static final` variable here, as all custom class initialization will be done *after* the `enum` constants have been constructed.